# Target a product in a list and increment/decrement its quantity

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of products and I want to be able to target each product and increment/decrement its quantity on button click. Please how can achieve this in plain Javascript?

This code can only capture the first item in the list, and that's because I used the item's index. How do I target the rest of the items dynamically and increase/decrease their quantity?

```
<ul id="checkout-bag">
            
    <li class="single-product">
        <div class="cart-product">
            <div class="thumb-desc">
                <h4>Product One</h4>
                <p>Description One</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-options">
            <div class="item-count">
                <button action="remove">-</button>
                <input type="text" value="1" class="item-quantity">
                <button action="add">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</li>


<li class="single-product">
        <div class="cart-product">
            <div class="thumb-desc">
                <h4>Product Two</h4>
                <p>Description Two</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-options">
            <div class="item-count">
                <button action="remove">-</button>
                <input type="text" value="1" class="item-quantity">
                <button action="add">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</li>


<li class="single-product">
        <div class="cart-product">
            <div class="thumb-desc">
                <h4>Product Three</h4>
                <p>Description Three</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-options">
            <div class="item-count">
                <button action="remove">-</button>
                <input type="text" value="1" class="item-quantity">
                <button action="add">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</li>


<li class="single-product">
        <div class="cart-product">
            <div class="thumb-desc">
                <h4>Product Four</h4>
                <p>Description Four</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-options">
            <div class="item-count">
                <button action="remove">-</button>
                <input type="text" value="1" class="item-quantity">
                <button action="add">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</li>


<li class="single-product">
        <div class="cart-product">
            <div class="thumb-desc">
                <h4>Product Five</h4>
                <p>Description Five</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-options">
            <div class="item-count">
                <button action="remove">-</button>
                <input type="text" value="1" class="item-quantity">
                <button action="add">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</li>
      
  </ul>
```

CSS

```
li {list-style-type:none;
    border: solid 1px gray;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    
}
```

JS

```
const checkoutBag = document.getElementById('checkout-bag');
const itemCount =  document.getElementsByClassName("item-quantity");

let itemQuantity = 1;
checkoutBag.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  const more = event.target.attributes.action.value; //add product
  const less = event.target.attributes.action.value; //remove product
  if(more =="add"){
    itemQuantity++
    document.getElementsByClassName("item-quantity")[0].value = itemQuantity;
  }
  if(less =="remove"){
    itemQuantity--
    document.getElementsByClassName("item-quantity")[0].value = itemQuantity;
   }

   if(itemQuantity < 1) {
    itemQuantity = 0;
  }
  document.getElementsByClassName("item-quantity")[0].value = itemQuantity;

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-heyrovsky-f982k?file=/src/index.js:0-501)**

The HTML/CSS code is the same and hasn't changed.

```js
const productOptions = document.querySelectorAll(".product-options");

productOptions.forEach((node) => {
  const itemCount = node.querySelector(".item-quantity");
  const add = node.querySelector("button[action='add']");
  const remove = node.querySelector("button[action='remove']");

  add.addEventListener("click", () => {
    itemCount.value = parseInt(itemCount.value, 10) + 1;
  });

  remove.addEventListener("click", () => {
    itemCount.value = parseInt(itemCount.value, 10) - 1;
  });
});
```

Comment: Work perfectly but refuse to work when I include it in my code. I suspect something in my code is stopping it from working but I can't figure out what  it is exactly. I'm a beginner programmer.

Comment: What's in the console? Maybe there are some errors.

Comment: I feel shamed of myself right now because I don't know much about using the console to figure things out. However, I will be happy to share with you the complete source code so you can take a look: [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/f5guwgmbnblbpyu/eCommConcept.zip/file). Basically when you click on the add to cart icon of any product, the item goes to the cart. Click the cart icon at the top menu of the site and you will see a list of all the products. Where you can be able to increment/decrement any product. That's where I'm having issues.

Comment: Console "says": `Uncaught TypeError: event.target.attributes.action is undefined`, you need to remove "attributes". Anyway, I've re-wrote the whole code https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-fermi-t8t47

Comment: Much thanks. I love the fact that you used ES6. I'm new to it and this will surely improve my knowledge.